# change of model but database not changed accordingly

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm new to golang.

Here's my code:

```golang
//main.go
type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string

}

type Log struct {
    gorm.Model
    Project Project
    User    User 
    CheckPoint string
    Status uint
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Password string
}

//...

db.AutoMigrate(&Project{}, &Log{}, &User{})
```

I want to:

```
Log.Project ==> Project.ID
Log.User ==> User.ID
```

But in the database logs table, it's:

```
desc logs;
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | datetime         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| check_point | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can't see the ProjectID nor the UserID.

Any guidance?

Thank you in advance.

> edit on 0825:

Hi there,
Maybe I need to explain myself firstly.

I need three tables: projects, users, logs.

In the logs, it records `which user` did `what` to `which project`.

I changed a little:

```golang
type Project struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Password string
}

type Log struct {
    gorm.Model
    ProjectID   uint
    UserID  uint
    CheckPoint string // ie: what to record
    Status uint // ie: record's status
}

...

db.Debug().Model(&Log{}).AddForeignKey("user_id", "users(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
db.Debug().Model(&Log{}).AddForeignKey("project_id", "projects(id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

When I ran the code,

```
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`logs`, CONSTRAINT `logs_project_id_projects_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`))
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`#sql-1a0f3_18`, CONSTRAINT `logs_user_id_users_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [has one](http://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html) relationship so the foreign key will be in the owned models (Project & User tables should have a `log_id`) column. Maybe what you want is a [belongs to](http://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html) relation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clue. I've looked at that post, but I'm not sure I've understood it correctly. So, changed the source, but errors occured. Without the two `AddForeignKey` line, no errors, but I don't see any foreign keys in the `show create table logs`. Would you like to reply with some code?